# When a solarian uses the Reflection revelation to reflect an attack, do they apply the original attacker's modifiers or their own?

Tags: class-feature, attack, starfinder

The [Reflection](http://www.starjammersrd.com/classes/Solarian/#Reflection_Su_Graviton_mode) revelation states:

> You can reflect ranged attacks back at your enemies. If you took the
>   total defense action on your last turn, or if you were fighting
>   defensively and spend 1 Resolve Point, as a reaction you can redirect
>   a ranged attack that misses you. **Select a new target within 30 feet
>   and make a ranged attack roll with a –4 penalty.** **If your attack hits,
>   the new target is damaged as if it had been the intended target of the
>   original ranged attack.**

Does this mean that when you hit, you apply all of the attacker's modifiers (weapon specialization, deadly aim, etc.) or all of your modifiers?  Or is it both, since you are also making an attack roll but they are doing the shooting?

Comment: There is nothing in the rules that allows you to use another creature ability scores, so I dont know why you are assuming this, and based on your comments on my (now deleted) answer, it seems like you have a very fixed idea in your mind. So, we need more information about what kind of answer you are looking for here.

Answer (score 2):

### Use your modifiers to hit.

The ability clearly states:

> ...make a ranged attack roll with a –4 penalty. If your attack hits...

This is now "your attack" and makes no mention of borrowing enemies stats/abilities/bonuses.

### Use the original attacker's modifiers to damage.

This one is a little more fuzzy, but seems to be the only way to interpret this emphasized quote:

> ..the new target is **damaged as if** it had been the intended target of the **original ranged attack**.

Therefore, enemy Weapon Specialization and such apply to the damage.